# People Results some users is not visible

Tags: sharepoint-online, search-results, people-search

I have a custom aspx page with a searchbox and a people result webpart. Some of my profiles (users) is visible but some of them are not visible.

They are only visible when i search for their name in the searchbox. 
What can be the problem? That they have not logged in to SharePoint (activated their accounts?)

Thanks

Comment: Nowadays even if the users did not log in, their profiles may be in SPO Admin Center (pls check), so that should not be the issue. Can you post the query and the web part settings that you are using?

Comment: Yes, they are in SPO Admin Center. The users is not visible in default searchpage so it cant be my query or my webparts settings.

Comment: I changed the setting "results per site" to 25, and now the users is visible.

Comment: I managed to fix the problem. I choosed "Dont remove duplicates" inside change query in webparts settings for search results webpart. Now all my users is visible. Thanks anyway.